# How can I do basic calculations in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, bc, math

I want to perform some mathematical operations in the shelll. For example:

```
5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7
```

I tried:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 read equ
 echo "scale=3; $equ" | bc -l
```

Expected output:

```
 17.929
```

My output:

```
 17.928
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bc is truncating, try this instead:

```
printf "%.3f\n" $(echo "$equ" | bc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `perl -e "print $expr"`,

e.g. `perl -e "print 5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7"` outputs `17.9285714285714`